# Music player in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a music player using C#.I using a QuartzTypeLib.dll which is present in
the Windows XP.
I get stuck when i click on the play button it plays the music very well and make main thread in a hung up state, so i play the music in other thread n still i am facing the same problem.
Any suggestion Please.

Comment: How certain are you that you have 2 threads?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the whole control would need to be created and initialised in another thread - ie, not just the Play() call.

Comment: then every click on the button has to divert to the same thread?

Comment: Yep. You should use delegates and Invoke() them so that it's thread-safe.